# Caching debate/forum entries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Just looking for a piece of advice. On one of our webpages we have a debate/forum site. Everytime a user request the debate page, he/she will get a list of all topics (and their count of answers etc.).

Too when the user request a specific topic/thread, all answers to the thread will be shown to the user a long with username, user picture, age, number of totalt forum-posts from the poster of the answer.

All content is currently retrieved by using an MySQL-query everytime the page is accessed. But this is however starting to get painfully slow (especially with large threads, +3000 answers).

I would like to cache the debate entries somehow, to speed up this proces. However the problem is, that if I cache the entries it self, number of post etc. (which is dynamic, of course), will not always be up to date.

Is there any smart way of caching the pages/recaching them when stuff like this is updated? :)

Thanks in advance,
fischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a tag or a name for the cache based on it's data.

For example for the post named *Jake's Post* you could create an md5 of the name, this would give you the tag *49fec15add24931728652baacc08b8ee*.

Now cache the contents and everything to do with this post against the tag *49fec15add24931728652baacc08b8ee*. When the post is updated or a comment is added go to the cache and delete everything associated with *49fec15add24931728652baacc08b8ee*.

Now there is no cache and it will be rebuilt when the next visitors arrives to new the post.

You could break this down further by having multiple tags per post. E.g you could have a tag for comments and answers, when a comment is added delete the comments tag, but not the answers tag. This reduces the work the server has to do when rebuilding the cache as only the comments are now missing.

There are number of libraries and frameworks that can aid you in doing this.

Jake

**EDIT**

I'd use files to store the data, more specifically the HTML output of the page. You can then do something like:

```
if(file_exists($tag))
{
    // Load the contents of the cache file here and output it
}
else
{
    // Do complex database look up and cache the file for later
}
```

Remember that frameworks like Zend have this sort of stuff built in. I would seriously considering using a framework.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sounds like a great way of doing it. I will lay out a database scheme for this. Do you think going for storing the cache in MySQL would be a good idea - or should I rather look into some other way of storing the cached entries instead (since i am going to be doing a rewrite of my code anyway, implementing the cache-mechanism)!?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic!

The first thing I'd look at is optimizing your database - even if you have to spend money upgrading the hardware, it will be significantly easier and cheaper than introducing a cache - fewer moving parts, fewer things that can go wrong...

If you can't squeeze more performance out of your database, the next thing I'd consider is de-normalizing the data a little. For instance, maintain a "reply_count" column, rather than counting the replies against each topic. This is ugly, but introduces fewer opportunities for things to go wrong - with a bit of luck, you can localize all the logic in your data access layer.

The next option I'd consider is to cache pages. For instance, just caching the "debate page" for 30 seconds should dramatically reduce the load on your database if you've got reasonable levels of traffic, and even if it all goes wrong, because you're caching the entire page, it will sort itself out the next time the page goes stale. In most situations, caching an entire page is okay - it's not the end of the world if a new post has appeared in the last 30 seconds and you don't see it on your page.

If you really have to provide more "up to date" content on the page, you might introduce caching at the database access level. I have, in the past, built a database access layer which cached the results of SQL queries based on hard-wired logic about how long to cache the results. In our case, we built a function to call the database which allowed you to specify the query (e.g. get posts for user), an array of parameters (e.g. username, date-from), and the cache duration. The database access function would cache results for the cache duration based on the query and the parameters; if the cache duration had expired, it would refresh the cache. 
This scheme was fairly bug-proof - as an end user, you'd rarely notice weirdness due to caching, and because we kept the cache period fairly short, it all sorted itself out very quickly.

Building up your page by caching snippets of content is possible, but very quickly becomes horribly complex. It's very easy to create a page that makes no sense to the end user due to the different caching policies - "unread posts" doesn't add up to the number of posts in the breakdown because of different caching policies between "summary" and "detail".